# Opening a CSV file which has date time field, getting opened in excel with "######"

Tags: file, excel, csv

While opening a CSV file in excel which has datetime field, it is getting opened in excel with the field marked as "######". Is there a way to format the excel file while opening the CSV file???

Answer (score 2):

- [##### Error Message](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/formulatips/qt/numbersign_err.htm)

> **#####** - Sometimes referred to as “Railroad tracks”, this error can be
>   caused by several conditions:
>
> - A number in a cell is too wide for the cell to display it.
> - The formula in the cell produces a result that is too wide for the
>     cell.
> - **There is a negative number in the cell that has been formatted for
>     dates or times. Dates and times in Excel must be positive values.**